# what is the difference between passing array to a method with array parameter and var-args in java?

Tags: java, arrays, overloading, method-call

I have gone through a note on var-args in java. I wondered what is the difference it make with the array parameter while calling a method.

```
public void doSomething(int[] a){
   // some logic here
}   
public void doSometing(int... a){
  // some logic here
}
```

the above two methods were called by

```
int[] x={1,2,3,4,5};
doSomething(x);
```

is both of them are same or some difference exists?

and is it possible to overload these two methods?

Comment: With varargs, you would not need to create the array. i.e. : ```doSomething(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);```

Answer (score 2):

The two method signatures are the same, and they do not allow overloading.

The only difference is that calling `doSomething(1, 2, 3)` with the vararg signature is allowed, while calling the same with the array signature results in an error.